# InApp purchases with iPhone original code and new code

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am integrating an inapp purchase into my iPhone application.  I am confused somewhat on this scenario.  I have a basketball tournament application that showed data dealing with the 2010 season.  I want to do an inapp purchase for the 2011 season.  My question is if someone already has the application they can upgrade it, and pay the new fee, but if they havent downloaded the application then I still want them to do a one time fee and have the 2011 season.  Is this possible? or do the new downloads have to still pay twice, the original code base and the inapp purchase?  I would like them to automatically have the 2011 season.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the app to add inapp purchasing and make the app iteself free to download (I assume its a paid app?).   Then charge for the 2011 with an inapp purchase.  If you go that route, those that have it already will upgrade (free) and then have to make an inapp purchase to get 2011 feature.  New users download the app (free) and also have to make inapp purchase.

Comment: That sounds like a plan to me.  How can I tell if that user has purchased the inapp purchase and show them the 2011 results?  I know you can store the value in NSUserDefaults, but that may not be a great solution if they delete the application and download it again, or get a new phone.  Is there a call to tell if they purchased the inapp application?

Comment: There's a nice tutorial and MKStoreKit [here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/) that I used to get started with inapp purchases.

Comment: I saw that but they use a third party framework I don't want to depend on.

Comment: No, it's not a framework, it's a couple ObjC classes which MK gives you the source code for.  You can see how it works, use it or modify it as needed, and compile it into your project.